# How to get details of geoLocation positionError cause

Tags: java, gwt, geolocation, gps

I am using gwt geolocation API (com.google.gwt.geolocation.client.Geolocation) to read the current location on a gwt mobile client.

Can I distinguish on the error, is it caused by not having gps functionality on or is it caused by not getting signal from gps? Does it try to get location also without location or is it only trying with gps?

*I write a gwt app with desktop machine through wired connection so it is not so easy to verify this by live testing.*

Comment: have to wait 2 days to be able to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocation API throws PositionError on failure. It has a code, that tells which is the case:

> `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` says gps is off.
>     
> `TIMEOUT` says it failed to retvieve value.

I have to check this variable and I know which is the case.